# E11000 duplicate key error collection: db.products index: product_id_1 dup key: { product_id: null }

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, express, mongoose

Please any one help me.
It's been two days i am blocked for getting all my products
I got duplicate key error while doing the GET action
I tried to remove({}) or deleteMany({}) or both or just one my db in my ctrllr but it's still on the same error...
I do not understand what is happening

This is my **product.ctrl** :

```js
const productCtrl = {
  sendDatasProductToMoongoose: async (req, res) => {
    try {
      await Product.deleteMany({})
                    .remove({});  
      const createdProducts = await Product.insertMany(data.products);
      console.log('Data Import Sucess createdProducts',createdProducts);
      res.send({ createdProducts});
    } catch (error) {
      res.status(500).send(error.message)
    }
  },
module.exports = productCtrl;
```

My **product.Router** :

```js
const express = require('express');
const productCtrl = require('../controllers/productCtrl');
const productRouter = express.Router();
productRouter.get('/seed', productCtrl.sendDatasProductToMoongoose )
module.exports = productRouter;
```

My **Server** :

```js
require('dotenv').config();
const express = require('express');
const cors = require("cors");


// require connexion db and run it 
const connectDB = require('./config/db');
const app = express();
connectDB();

// fonct. middleware intégrée dans Express :
// Il analyse les req' entrantes avc des charges utiles JSON et est basé sur un analyseur de corps.
// parse les req http en json
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cors());


app.use('/api/products', require('./routes/productRouter.js'))
app.use('/api/users', require('./routes/userRouter.js'))


//Test
/* app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Server is Ready')
}) */

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server running on ${PORT}`));
```

My req on Postman :
***GET***             **http://localhost:5000/api/products/seed**

And my error :
E11000 duplicate key error collection: dbname.products index: product_id_1 dup key: { product_id: null }

**My file data** :

```js
const bcrypt = require( 'bcryptjs');

const data = {
  users: [
    {
      name: 'Nemo',
      email: 'nemo@mail.com',
      password: bcrypt.hashSync('1111', 8),
      isAdmin: true,
    },
     {
      name: 'Dori',
      email: 'dori@mail.com',
      password: bcrypt.hashSync('1111', 8),
      isAdmin: false,
    },
  ],
  products: [
    {
    name:"Pendentif Lunaire en Cristal de Swarovski",
    category: "Pendentif",
    image: '../../frontend/public/images/Moon-pendant.png',
    material:"cristal de Swarovski,  argent 925",
    price: 45,
    countInStock: 3
    },
    {
    name:"Pendentif Labradorite",
    category: "Pendentif",
    image:'../../frontend/public/images/Labradorite-pendant-big.png',
    material:"labradorite,argent 925",
    price: 80,
    countInStock: 2
    },
     {
    name:"Pendentif Labradorite",
    category: "Pendentif",
    image:'../../frontend/public/images/Labradorite-pendant-medium.png',
    material:"labradorite,argent 925",
    price: 45,
    countInStock: 3
    },
    {
    name:"Pendentif Oeil du Tigre",
    category: "Pendentif",
    image:'../../frontend/public/images/EyeTiger-pendant.png',
    material:"labradorite,argent 925",
    price: 45,
    countInStock: 3
    },
    {
    name:"Pendentif en Quartz Rose",
    category: "Pendentif",
    image: '../../frontend/public/images/Quartz-pendant.png',
    material:"améthiste, argent 925",
    price: 35,
    countInStock: 6,
  }
  ]
}

module.exports = data;
```

Comment: **My Product Model : **

Answer (score 0):

It seems that "product_id" is a unique index inside your schema, right? And you are trying to insert a new document with a "product_id" of null value, having an already existing document with this value in the same index.

When you insert a document with an empty value on a unique index, the value will be stored as null. (I'll leave that part to the docs):

> If a document does not have a value for the indexed field in a unique
> index, the index will store a null value for this document. Because of
> the unique constraint, MongoDB will only permit one document that
> lacks the indexed field. If there is more than one document without a
> value for the indexed field or is missing the indexed field, the index
> build will fail with a duplicate key error.

You could delete the entry with the null value at product_id and it should work.

But I would highly suggest building in some validation before inserting your products to make sure it does not happen again.

Comment: Thanks for your helping.I thinks I get it but I'm not sure where I could delete the entry, in the productReducer ?and about some validation in the productctrl ?

Comment: You can delete it manually inside your database manager. Are you not using one? And could you perhaps edit your question and share with us your Product model? So  that we can check how was your "product_id" index declared.

Comment: I reset my db on Mongodb Compass but after refreshing it still just one product.

Comment: Here is my Product model : ```js const mongoose = require('mongoose'); 
const productSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  image: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  price: {
    type: Number,
    required: true
  },
  material: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
 
  countInStock: {
    type: Number,
    required: true
  },
}, {
  timestamps: true
})   const Product = mongoose.model('Product', productSchema);

module.exports = Product; ```

Comment: My prdct.Reducer : `const initialStateForGetProducts = {
  products: []
};  export const getProductsReducer = (state = initialStateForGetProducts, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case actionTypes.GET_PRODUCTS_REQUEST:
      return {
        loading: true,
        products:[] 
      }
    case actionTypes.GET_PRODUCTS_SUCESS:
      return {
        loading: false,
        products: action.payload
      }default:
      return state;
  }
}`